# SQL aliases for subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

I have a problem with following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM Images 
   WHERE create_user_id=:user_id) RIGHT INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM PhotoGallery) ON id=centity_id
 )
 ORDER BY centity_id;
```

I am getting 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias error and I know I need to give those tables aliases, but whatever I do, I always get error. Could anyone help me to solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: i think you have to provide table alias to subquery e.g (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE create_user_id=:user_id) as TableA

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Images i RIGHT JOIN
       PhotoGallery p ON i.id=p.centity_id
 WHERE i.create_user_id=:user_id
 ORDER BY p.centity_id
```

Based on your DDL and your desired output join might be `RIGHT`, `INNER` or `LEFT`, but not `RIGHT INNER JOIN`

Comment: @kokoseq You're certainly welcome. Please, consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it was helpful. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your subqueries need an alias.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT *
   FROM Images 
   WHERE create_user_id=:user_id
  ) i RIGHT INNER JOIN 
  PhotoGallery pg
  ON i.id=pg.centity_id
 )
 ORDER BY centity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a dbms that supported "RIGHT INNER JOIN". Choose one of

- INNER JOIN, or
- RIGHT OUTER JOIN, or
- RIGHT JOIN (which  should mean the same as RIGHT OUTER JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a select *, you don't need to do a sub-query.

```
SELECT * FROM Images 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN PhotoGallery ON id=centity_id
WHERE create_user_id = :user_id
ORDER BY centity_id;
```